# Dual boot Windows 7 and Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have a Vaio notebook with Windows 7 64 bit. 
I want to dual boot it with Arch Linux. 
I have three primary partitions: Recovery, System reserved (Active and Boot) and the Windows `C:` drive. I have resized  the large partition with the the Windows `C:` drive. 
Now I have an empty space where I could create the Linux partition, but I am lost as concerns the boot loader.

According to Arch documentation, using Windows 7/8 boot loader restricts me to a Fat32 Linux partition, really a no go. So I can use GRUB or SysLinux. As for Syslinux,  I have read that using `chain.c32` can prevent Windows 7 hibernation. As for GRUB, the new version is very complex, do I really  need it for such a simple task? Secondly, Arch Docs say that a  post-MBR gap of about 1 to 2 MiB is recommended to provide sufficient room for embedding GRUB's `core.img`. How do I check if I have it and what to do if I don't have it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use **ArchLinux** on all my machines.

Unfortunately, the ArchLinux installer is no longer as beginner friendly as it once was but installing Arch or Gentoo is a good learning experience.

Linux doesn't name partitions in terms of `C:\, D:\, E:\` instead it will be `/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, /dev/sdb1`. Note that *nix differentiates between partitions on the same drive vs physically separate drives. The letter **X** in `/dev/sdX` specifies the drive and the number **#** `/dev/sda#` specifies the partition.

Furthermore, the **raw** `/dev/sdX#` device nodes are separate from their **mountpoints** (traditionally `/media/<label>`, with **SystemD** now `/run/media/<user>/<label>`). However, for the current ArchLinux installer you will manually mount `/` (root partition; equivalent to Windows `C:\`) to `/mnt` for the purposes of the installation.

My recommendation is to first download the [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). This will help you make sense of your partitions and allow you to prepare them for the installer via a graphical (GUI) means.

You can only have 4 primary partitions using a traditional DOS/MBR partition table, so you may choose to make the 4th partition `extended` and inside that create `logical` partitions. Choose `EXT4` for your ArchLinux partition. You should also create a `SWAP` partition (2GB recommended; equivalent to Windows `pagefile` or `hiberfil.sys`) for hibernation and virtual/overflow RAM support. I don't think you'll need a separate `/boot` partition.

Additionally, I strongly recommend that you choose the [GRUB2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners_Guide#GRUB) bootloader. It offers a lot of features (such as ISO booting) and works basically "out of the box" with ArchLinux. You can generate a config file using `os-prober` and `grub-mkconfig` that will create a boot entry for Windows. Some of that stuff on wiki is regarding UEFI or alternative boot methods which shouldn't concern you.

Best of luck!

Comment: +1 One question still unclear. When I run `# modprobe dm-mod` and `# grub-install --recheck /dev/sda`, will the post-MBR gap be sufficient to accommodate GRUB `core.img`?

Comment: The MBR is the first 512 bytes (440 of which is reserved for the bootloader) and I've never had an issue with that. 

Just use [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners_Guide#GRUB)

`pacman -S grub os-prober && grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX && grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Oh and FYI no need to load the `dm-mod` module, it's for reading encrypted drives.